# standard errors for computing means via OLS regression

Tags: regression, mean, standard-error

Suppose I have a variable $y_{i,t}$ which is say a well-being index for individual of type $i$ in month $t$. There are 2 types of individual, $A$,$B$, which are mutually exclusive, and three non-overlapping periods $t1$, $t2$, $t3$, so that the entire sample periods consists of those three periods.

If I want to estimate the mean of $y$ for each type of individual and each period, along with standard errors for the hypothesis that the mean is 0 for that individual type and period, I can either do it normally (selecting the relevant part of the dataset and computing the mean), or I could run a regression:

$y_{it} = \beta_1 D_A D_{t1} + \beta_2 D_A D_{t2} + \beta_3 D_A D_{t3} + \beta_4 D_B D_{t1} + \beta_5 D_B D_{t2} + \beta_6 D_B D_{t4}+\epsilon_{it}$

where $D_A$ equals one if individual is of type $A$ and 0 otherwise, and $D_{t1}$ is 1 if we are in time $t1$ and 0 otherwise. The remaining variables are defined analogously.

My interpretation is that $\beta_1$ is the mean of the dependent variable for individuals of type $A$ in period $1$. Is this the correct interpretation?

Also, is it necessary to adjust the standard errors in any way? Since periods and individual types are mutually exclusive, I assume not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation of $\beta_1$ is correct. It should be pretty easy to verify by comparing the 6 coefficients to the 6 type x period means.

You should cluster the standard errors by individual to reflect that you have repeated observations of the same individuals over time.